# Meaning of "take it to go"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

For example, I buy a pizza at a restaurant, and I don't want to finish eating it there.

Can I say "take it to go" in this case? Does "take it to go" even have a meaning? If yes, is it the same as "take away"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I would like a pizza to go* is the US idiomatic way to order food in a place where you can stay and eat or take away and you do not plan to stay there.

*I would like a takeaway pizza* would be the equivalent British version

If you are already sitting and eating food and would like to take the rest with you, you can ask for a "doggy bag" or in case of a pizza, you can ask them to box the rest for you.

Comment: "Take away" is the normal phrase in England (I believe it's "carry out" in Scotland). "To go" is the American version. Presumably the meaning is "to walk away with".

Comment: Updated. To Go has taken over the rest of Europe via Starbucks - I have heard Brits here in Holland use "To Go" as well